# What software is used to animate and create the Cat in Talking Tom application in iphone

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es, 3d

I was curious to know what software is used to create the 3D Cat in the talking tom app in iphone. Is it done with OpenGL ES?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/talking-tom-cat/id377194688?mt=8

Comment: Are you asking about the software for displaying the 3D cat (very likely Open GL ES on the iPhone), or the software tools for authoring the 3D model and animation for the cat?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know what software has been used to create the 3d model and the animation for the cat. I am doing quite a bit of researching on that. I have stumbled on this book -http://www.amazon.com/iPhone-Apps-Blender-SIO2-Open-Source/dp/0470574925

Comment: Can someone also advise how long does it take to learn Open GL ES for someone who does not have any 3d experience. I am looking at SIO2+Blender mainly because blender is free.

Comment: @nishantcm : I followed the video tutorials, It took 10 days for me to learn :P Hoped I could be faster :(

Comment: @nishantcm : Have updated my answer for the links.

Comment: What road should I take for this app - Blender+SIO2 or OpenGL ES? Which is easier to learn and program?

Comment: @nishantcm : SIO2 is a mobile game development engine which has its advantages over developing things from scratch. now it depends upon you, if you want to learn things deeply or finish up things quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well if it's related to talking tom then there is no OpenGL ES use... they are simply using images and animating them, something like this:

```
    aniImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImage* opa1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o1.png"];
UIImage* opa2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o2.png"];
UIImage* opa3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o3.png"];
UIImage* opa4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o4.png"];
UIImage* opa5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o5.png"];
UIImage* opa6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o6.png"];
UIImage* opa7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o7.png"];
UIImage* opa8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o8.png"];
UIImage* opa9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o9.png"];
UIImage* opa10 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o10.png"];
UIImage* opa11 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o11.png"];
UIImage* opa12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o12.png"];
UIImage* opa13 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o13.png"];
UIImage* opa14 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o14.png"];
UIImage* opa15 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o15.png"];
UIImage* opa16 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o16.png"];
UIImage* opa17 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o17.png"];
UIImage* opa18 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"o18.png"];
NSArray *imgsArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:opa1, opa2, opa3, opa4, 
                          opa5, opa6, opa7, opa8, opa9, opa10, opa11, opa12, opa13, opa14, opa15, opa16, opa17, opa18, nil];
[aniImage setAnimationImages:imagesOpacity];
[aniImage setAnimationRepeatCount:1.0];
[aniImage setAnimationDuration:0.2];
```

If you want to see all the images they are using follow these steps:

1. Download the free version to your iPhone/iPad.
2. Transfer your purchases on your Mac or Windows computer.
3. Then drag the ipa file from **Library** -> **Apps** to your desktop (just drag the app icon from iTunes to desktop).
4. Rename the .ipa file to .zip file.
5. Extract this zip file.  You will get a folder named "Payload" in it.
6. Open the .app file (it will open on Windows automatically because it is a folder on Windows, 
   on Mac right click on it and select **Show package content**.
7. In the .app folder you will find a folder which contains all the images used by the above function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @nishantcm did you create?

Answer (score 1):

Go for [OpenGLES](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html)

Video Tutorials: http://vimeo.com/6381001

Blog Post : http://www.71squared.com/2009/03/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-1/

Comment: What are my alternatives to (SIO2+Blender) and OpenGL ES? Can I use blender generated models with OpenGL ES?